# More detailed historical trx info (fee, sat per byte, transferred value in trx, from, to) from electrumx server?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, electrum, full-node, electrum-server

I run bitcoin full node and Electrumx server over it for getting historical data.
The methods that I frequently used were "blockchain.scripthash.get_history" and "blockchain.transaction.get" and verbose mode was true always.
But I could not get some clear info about **transaction fee**, **transfer value**, **exact from/to**, **sat/bytes** , and so on after some days.
Is there exist the straightforward method for getting these data from ElectrumX server?